# Top border of item sticked to top of navbar

Tags: html, css, list, navbar, margin

I have an example navbar here: http://jsfiddle.net/HBXku/447/.

I want to make the  `border-top` colorful elements to be sticked to the top of navbar section (not floating XX px down the navbar top). I want also to make the text of item as much vertically aligned as possible. After couple of hours trying I cannot achieve any result...

Answer (score 1):

I did not fully understand what needs to be done, but it seems like something like this

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.navigation {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation-list-item {
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: #292929;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.navigation-list {
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    margin: 0;
}

.navigation-list-item a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.navigation-list-item.menu1 {
    border-top: 10px solid #ccad09;
}
.navigation-list-item.menu2 {
    border-top: 10px solid #cc7e39;
}
.navigation-list-item.menu3 {
    border-top: 10px solid #cc374b;
}
.navigation-list-item.menu4 {
    border-top: 10px solid #cc00b0;
}
.navigation-list-item.menu5 {
    border-top: 10px solid #c653cc;
}
.navigation-list-item.menu6 {
    border-top: 10px solid #5e2ecc;
}
.navigation-list-item.menu7 {
    border-top: 10px solid #3d47cc;
}
.navigation-list-item.menu8 {
    border-top: 10px solid #0a8ecc;
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar clearfix">
    <nav class="navigation">
        <ul class="navigation-list">
            <li class="navigation-list-item menu1"><a href="#works">Menu item1</a></li>
            <li class="navigation-list-item menu2"><a href="#features">Menu item2</a></li>
            <li class="navigation-list-item menu3"><a href="#opinions">Menu item3</a></li>
            <li class="navigation-list-item menu4"><a href="#blog">Menu item4</a></li>
            <li class="navigation-list-item menu5"><a href="#company">Menu item5</a></li>
            <li class="navigation-list-item menu6"><a href="#team">Menu item6</a></li>
            <li class="navigation-list-item menu7"><a href="#prices">Menu item7</a></li>
            <li class="navigation-list-item menu8"><a href="#contact">Menu item8</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**Without flex with logo**

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.logo {
    width: 80px;
    float: left;
}
.topbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation-list-item {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #292929;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.navigation {
    position: absolute;
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.navigation-list {
    padding: 0;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.navigation-list-item a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.navigation-list-item.menu1 {
    border-top: 10px solid #ccad09;
}

.navigation-list-item.menu2 {
    border-top: 10px solid #cc7e39;
}
.navigation-list-item.menu3 {
    border-top: 10px solid #cc374b;
}
.navigation-list-item.menu4 {
    border-top: 10px solid #cc00b0;
}
.navigation-list-item.menu5 {
    border-top: 10px solid #c653cc;
}
.navigation-list-item.menu6 {
    border-top: 10px solid #5e2ecc;
}
.navigation-list-item.menu7 {
    border-top: 10px solid #3d47cc;
}
.navigation-list-item.menu8 {
    border-top: 10px solid #0a8ecc;
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar clearfix">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://codepen.io/assets/avatars/user-avatar-80x80-bdcd44a3bfb9a5fd01eb8b86f9e033fa1a9897c3a15b33adfc2649a002dab1b6.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <nav class="navigation">
    <ul class="navigation-list">
      <li class="navigation-list-item menu1"><a href="#works">Menu item1</a></li>
      <li class="navigation-list-item menu2"><a href="#features">Menu item2</a></li>
      <li class="navigation-list-item menu3"><a href="#opinions">Menu item3</a></li>
      <li class="navigation-list-item menu4"><a href="#blog">Menu item4</a></li>
      <li class="navigation-list-item menu5"><a href="#company">Menu item5</a></li>
      <li class="navigation-list-item menu6"><a href="#team">Menu item6</a></li>
      <li class="navigation-list-item menu7"><a href="#prices">Menu item7</a></li>
      <li class="navigation-list-item menu8"><a href="#contact">Menu item8</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to do. But is it possible to achieve it without using flexbox?

Comment: Thanks! Working as well. Bonus question: what if I want to add logo image which will be always to the left of navbar, and the whole navbar will have 60 % width of screen and be centered?

Comment: I've just added centering of navbar and styles for logo

Comment: Another point for You : ) . Now I try to make it more complicated (sorry). How to make logo and navbar to be centered and with width: 60%? Now logo is sticked to the left of the screen. I want to make logo sticked to the left part of navbar so they together (navbar elements + logo) expand for 60 % of width.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add

```
.navigation-list{
   margin: 0;
   padding:0;
}
```

Because that class is added to ul and ul has margin by default in the browsers